# self.title sets navigationController and tabBarItem's title? Why?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I do this in a UIViewController for one of my tabs:

```
self.title = @"Welcome";
```

However, it's overwriting whatever I have for the tabBarItem. I have tried:

```
self.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
```

and

```
[self.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconHome.png"] tag:0];
```

But still, self.title overwrites the tabBarItem, regardless of whether I am trying the two latter pieces of code *after* the title has been set. The code even runs without errors, but the `self.tabBarItem.title` or `initWithTitle` doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

OK, I figured it out! Here's what I am doing:

```
self.title = @"Title for TabBarItem"; // TabBarItem.title inherits the viewController's self.title
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title for NavigationBar";
```

the `navigationBar` would inherit self.title, unless otherwise set using `self.navigationItem.title`

Comment: I was running into exactly the same problem when using a UINavigationController within a UITabController. This solved it.

Comment: This works for me. Great for changing just the top title based on content even if the view controller doesn't change.

Comment: Quick note that the order of these two lines matters.

Answer (score 60):

```
//set nav item title
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"zurück";
```

**this did it for me :=)**
(nothing of the above worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self setTitle:@"Welcome"];

UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed: image] tag:0];
[self setTabBarItem:item];
[item release];
```

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't work either. "Welcome" (title for self) is always the same for the tabBar. Very frustrating, actually.

I spoke to a dev friend who said the only way he was able to do it differently, was to set the title of the navigationController in IB, and then not set self.title in the code. But that just seems odd. If no one comes with a solution here, I might file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Out Of interest where are you doing your tab bar setup?

The sample above comes from the init method of my controller.

I don't use interface builder for my views (their either custom or created in loadView). That may be the difference.

Comment: Yeah, I am using IB, but tried to init the tabs in each UIViewController (NavigationController). I'll have a look at what happens if I place the above code in an init method in the UIViewController...

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, but i solve this issue like this. I set the title and image of tabBarItem right after i created them in appDelegate.

This is what i have done:

```
[viewController setTitle:@"controllerTitle"];
[[viewController tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Custome Title for tab"];
[[viewController tabBarItem] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]];
```