# How to do tabBar.title != navBar.title?

Tags: iphone

I have tab bar, and navigation bar in it. In navigation bar I have table view. The problem is, when I set the title to the tab bar in IB, and next set the title in table view, tab bar title is changing to title from table view, and I have the same title in navigation bar and tab bar, but I want have different titles there.

How to set tab bar title to be different then in van bar?

Comment: Can you just try to do both programmatically?

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

This link also has a similar but different solution:
[self.title sets navigationController and tabBarItem's title? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540718/self-title-sets-navigationcontroller-and-tabbaritems-title-why/1596277#1596277)

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the answer you linked to, but good to see different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Your title"
```