# setting self.title change the tabbaritem title, how can i prevent that?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm confusing.

All I want to do is setting title "one" to the viewcontroller
and title "two" to the tab bar item that show it.

What happen now is :
I set "one" to the tabbaritem in Interface builder.
When I set in the viewDidLoad  self.title="two", the tab bar item text is changed also to "two"

How can I prevent that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Chek out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540718/self-title-sets-navigationcontroller-and-tabbaritems-title-why/1596277#1596277) in case it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a normal UIViewController, `self.title` refers to the same object as `self.tabBarItem.title`. You can't change them independently.

If you want to display a title somewhere other than in the UITabBarItem, you could add a UILabel to the view and set its text.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `self.navigationItem.title`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:idx] setTitle:@"text"];
```