# Why does the tabbar items label change when Pushing using UINavigationController?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, title

I created UITabController with three tabs. One Tab has UINavigationController that pushes three controllers A,B, &C.

When I push segue from A to B or B to C, I change the titles on A, B, &C. Changing the title on A, B or C also changes the title of my third tab item in the main tabController. How can I make the tab bar items labels on the main Controller fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this thread fixed my problem: [self.title sets navigationController and tabBarItem's title? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540718/self-title-sets-navigationcontroller-and-tabbaritems-title-why)

You basically need to set your title in your viewDidLoad method in your UIViewController (which is displayed by the UINavigationController) like this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

instead of this

```
self.title = @"Your Title";
```