# How to acces the right navigation controller inside storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

You can see my storyboard over here.

[image]

My question is now how should I access in code the different navigation controllers in a correct way. Because sometimes I get some troubles with it.

For example what is the difference between accessing NAV 1 and accessing NAV 2 or NAV 3 ... .

Any help? Thank you

**Code for setting title**

```
- (void)addEvent:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"pressed event");


    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // set the addController's event store to the current event store.
    addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
    addController.editViewDelegate = dataSource;
    // present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
    addController.title = @"";
    self.title = @"";
    self.parentViewController.title = @"";
    self.navigationController.parentViewController.title = @"";
    self.navigationController.visibleViewController.title = @"";
    self.navigationController.title = @"";
    self.navigationItem.title = @"";
    addController.navigationItem.title = @"";
    addController.navigationController.title = @"";
    self.tabBarController.navigationController.title = @"";
    [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in your storyboard itself.

Nav1 is the root navigation controller that pushes the screens upto the tab 1 .There you are creating separate Navigation controllers and the flow of another navigation is started.so to get the Nav 2 and remaining you have to depend on the tabcontroller tab 1

EDIT :
Setting the title in a  VC

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title"];
```

ReEdit:

Insert a navigation controller and modally present the navigation controller

```
EKEventEditViewController* myController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
myController.title = @"My Title";

UINavigationController* modalController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
[self presentViewController:modalController animated:YES completion:nil];

[modalController release];
[myController release];
```

Comment: Oké, let's say for example that I push a modal VC onto my viewcontroller inside NAV4. But I want to set the title of that modal VC. How can I do that?

Comment: @StefGeelen : uodated the answer

Comment: @StefGeelen : self.title sets the title

Comment: @StefGeelen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540718/self-title-sets-navigationcontroller-and-tabbaritems-title-why chk this

Comment: I've edited my question with what I've tried so far but still got the add event title on the modal VC

Comment: @StefGeelen which one is your EKEventEditViewController in storyboard?

Comment: You can't see it on my story board because I push it modally?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24184/discussion-between-lithu-t-v-and-stef-geelen)

Comment: @StefGeelen : ok now i modified the code a bit now its working for me.Check it.The change is modally presented .. self.navigationcontroller to self