# Searching a UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to do a search in a UITableview. I have implemented the UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate method at the correct way. This is how my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        Contact *contact = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.name,contact.firstName];
        NSLog(@"CellForRowAtIndexPath contact text is %@",text);
        cell.textLabel.text = text;


        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];


    }else{
    NSString *alphabet = [firstIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@",alphabet];
    NSArray *contacts = [listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    Contact *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.name,contact.firstName];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;


       [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

And this is my filterContentForSearchText method

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

    for (Contact *contact in listContent)
    {
        NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",contact.name,contact.firstName];
        NSRange range = [searchString rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:contact];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is. In my cellForRowAtIndexPath it returns me the correct data. But the tableview itselfs keeps given me the NO RESULTS label.

Any help with this?

Comment: [This is what you're looking for!](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-searching-table-view.html)

Comment: I've followed a better tutorial then that. But still got the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an array to show data in table(showDataArray)
2. Use an array to store all input values(dataArray)
3. Use showDataArray to populate your table always
4. In the searchfield when charecter range changes call a method to filter the data using predicate from dataArray
5. Save the value to showDataArray
6. Call for table reloadData

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial [how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/)  ..

Just see the method **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** in which how to set the search array when user searched record from **UISearchBar**...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please take a look at this question also ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768859/how-to-acces-the-right-navigation-controller-inside-storyboard/14769261#comment20677346_14769261

Answer (score 0):

First add [UISearchBar on top of UITabelView documentation](http://www.iphonedeveloperdiary.com/2010/07/adding-a-uisearchbar-to-top-part-tableview/)

And then Take Two `NSMutableArray` and **add one array to  another array** in `ViewDidLoad` method such like,

```
self.listOfTemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array no - 1
self.ItemOfMainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"YorArrayList", nil]; // array no - 2 

[self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray]; // add 2array to 1 array
```

**And Write following delegate Method of UISearchBar**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
        NSString *name = @"";
        NSString *firstLetter = @"";

    if (self.listOfTemArray.count > 0)
         [self.listOfTemArray removeAllObjects];
    
        if ([searchText length] > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < [self.ItemOfMainArray count] ; i = i+1)
                {
                        name = [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i];
                        
                        if (name.length >= searchText.length)
                        {
                                firstLetter = [name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                                //NSLog(@"%@",firstLetter);
                                
                                if( [firstLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText] == NSOrderedSame )
                                {
                                    // strings are equal except for possibly case
                                    [self.listOfTemArray addObject: [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                                    NSLog(@"=========> %@",self.listOfTemArray);
                                }
                         }
                 }
         }
         else
         {
             [self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray ];
         }
        
        [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

And Write in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
        
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.listOfTemArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
  
    return cell;
}
```